# real time - active noise control

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, control-systems, adaptive-filters

I am trying to implement an adaptive filter for system identification and active noise control for realtime signal processing on an FPGA using Labview. For system identification, I implemented the following adaptive filter:

$$g(n+1)=g(n)+\mu \odot d^*(n)\odot e(n)$$

with

$$e(n)=np(n)-g(n)\odot d(n)$$

with $\odot$ denoting elementwise multiplication, $g(n) \in \mathbb{C}^N$ being the frequency response function (Fourier-Transform of the impulse response), the number of samples $N=2048$, $\mu$ being the step size parameter, $()^*$ denoting the complex conjugate, $d(n)\in\mathbb{C}^N$ being the Fourier-Transform of the loudspeaker driving data (White Noise) and $np(n)\in\mathbb{C}^N$ being the Fourier-Transform of the measured signal at the microphone. The identified impulse response and frequency response function is plausible and meets my expectations, which makes me assume that it is correct.

I am now trying to use the same equation for Feedback - Active Noise Control using the identified frequency response function. For this purpose I drive another loudspeaker with a sinusoidal wave and calculate the cancelling loudspeaker driving function in the frequency domain via:

$$d(n+1)=d(n)-\mu \odot g^* \odot e(n) $$

with $e(n)$ being the Fourier-Transform of the pressure measured at the error sensor. I use $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(d(n+1))$ to calculate the samples to drive my loudspeaker with.

**The Problem:** the adaptive filter diverges immediately even for small step sizes and I think that the speaker is about to explode. After looking through my code for many hours I can't find the error. Now I'm wondering: Should the ANC-equation work or does it only work in special cases like for periodic signals?

Comment: Have you tried your solution in simulation, like Matlab/Simulink, Python, etc.?

No point in trying a real-life solution if the concept does not work in theory.

Comment: Yes I first programmed the solution in Matlab. The system identification algorithm works in theory and seems to work in real-life. For $\mu = 1/(||d^H d||_2)$ the algorithm basically is direct inversion of each frequency bin and converges in 1 step.

The ANC algorithm seems to work in theory (at least for simple impulse reponses like [1 0 0 0 ...] ) and is based on a very similar equation as the system identification algorithm but seems to fail in real-life.

Comment: Ok, can you sample the noise you have in real-life and simulate your algorithm with this data?

Comment: Well, try sampling the noise you have in real-life. Run the Matlab simulation for a significant time (like 1-2 seconds). Depending on the results, it will tell you if you have an algorithmitic problem or an implementation problem.